# If a function is jointly concave over $x_0,x_1,\cdots x_T$ then is it concave over $x_1,x_2 \cdots x_T$?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have a function $f(x)$ defined as follows $$f(x)=f_1(x_0,x_1)+f_2(x_0,x_2)+\cdots f_T(x_0,x_T)$$ each of the individual function $f_i(x_0,x_i)$ is non-negative and jointly concave over $(x_0,x_i)$ therefore the summation is also concave. If I fix $x_0=c$ then the new function becomes $$f_c(x)=f_1(c,x_1)+f_2(c,x_2)+\cdots f_T(c,x_T)$$ My question is as follows. Is $f_c(x)$ a concave function of $x_1,x_2 \cdots x_T$? Any help in this regard will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
f_c(\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y)&=\sum_{i=1}^Tf_i(\lambda c+(1-\lambda)c, \lambda x_i + (1-\lambda) y_i)\\
&\geq \sum_{i=1}^T [\lambda f_i(c,x_i)+(1-\lambda)f_i(c,y_i)]
\\&=\lambda f_c(c,x) + (1-\lambda)f_c(c,y)
\end{align}

Comment: So means $f_c(x)$ will be individually concave function?\

Comment: what does "individually concave function" mean? Do you mean if all other variables are fixed, is it still a concave function? answer is yes if that is what you mean.

Comment: I am very sorry for asking this. But can you please provide your help in understanding this problem. (I am sorry again for directing your attention to another question but I will be very thankful for your help) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2636419/where-am-i-wrong-in-this-prove-of-concavity